# Capstone fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdint.h': No such file or directory

Tags: windows-10, pip

I'm trying to install [pwntools](https://github.com/Gallopsled/pwntools) on Windows 10 with pip.

I got this error:

```
 C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_Username\capstone\src\include\capstone.h(11) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdint.h': No such file or directory
```

Note: I replace my real name by Username on the path.

How to solve this?

EDIT: FORGET TO INSTALL PWNTOOLS ON WINDOWS! I got other problems after solve this one and I finally gave up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/126279/c99-stdint-h-header-and-ms-visual-studio). I use the Visual C++ 2008 Command prompt and stdint.h is missing for this version.

So I use the Visual C++ 2017 Command prompt instead.

Comment: Thanks, it help me. For those who has Visual Studio 2017 and can't find the Command prompt, go to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\`, go to the folder you see, in my case it was `Enterprise` but it can be other than that. Continue to `Common7\Tools\`, open Cmd and run `VsDevCmd.bat`. It will change the environment so you will be able to use the VS 2017 tools.